# www subdomain working, unkown reason

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, virtualhost, debian-jessie

i have a vServer with a domain (from strato) running on Apache2. My only running site has the following vHost:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".                                                                                                                            
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf                                                                                                                                         
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/fullchain.pem                                                                                                                   
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/privkey.pem                                                                                                                  
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf                                                                                                                                           
ServerName www.example.de
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

and the following apache2ctl -S:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx::x. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
    default server www.example.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vps.conf:2)
    port 443 namevhost www.example.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vps.conf:2)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

After all i read i should not be able to reach my server under www.example.com, because i never configured my DNS-entry to match that subdomain. I only have the entry example.de with the IPs set accordingly. But it do want to reach my Server under www so i changed ServerName to www.example.com. Funny thing is, that i'm able to reach my server under www.example.com AND example.com and there is no certificate error.

This is something i don't understand, but im willing to understand, because it bothers me.

FYI: The server is running owncloud.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question afterall?

Comment: Why i am able to reach the server with www.example.com AND example.com? + I never configure the subdomain www, so more specifically: Why am i able to reach the server under www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is "default server".  Apache always has a "default server" ... which will accept connections for any site where the hostname doesn't match anything defined.

In this case, as your logs correctly show:

`default server www.example.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vps.conf:2)`

www.example.de is your default site, and any un-matched hostnames will be sent to that site.

I generally recommend to people to setup a standard "404" site for the default site to tell people that they did not reach the correct site... and then make sure your proper domains are properly defined.

Comment: i understand, that every request goes to www.example.de, but how does the DNS handle my request for www.example.de? Directing it to example.de and apache then redirects it to my default site? Because test.example.de throws a DNS error....

Comment: DNS does not do http redirects.  Ever.  DNS is just a name-resolution service...  It takes a name and presents an IP.  Only a web server can do a http redirect.